# Unknown reason for invalid syntax python

Tags: python

I have to find best distance length for travelling for a couple. It is from codewarriors. Link here https://www.codewars.com/kata/55e7280b40e1c4a06d0000aa/train/python

I solved in other way, but I just want to know why there is an invalid syntax.
t is a max distance. k is a number of cities they can visit. 'ls' is a list of distances among cities Thank you in advance.

```
def choose_best_sum(t, k, ls):
    start = 0
    end = 5
    distances = []
    while len(distances) != k:
        if sum(ls[start:end]) < t:
            start += 1
            end += 1
        else:
            distances.append(sum(ls[start:end])

    return max(distances)
```

Comment: Problem is missing a closing paren.  Should be: `distances.append(sum(ls[start:end]))`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your missing a ')' on the else statement line.

Answer (score 0):

Your parentheses are not closed properly on

```py
 distances.append(sum(ls[start:end])
```

Notice two opening parentheses but only one closing.

Close it off and you're good to go

```py
distances.append(sum(ls[start:end]))
```